# emgu GPU Blob detection

Tags: opencv, emgucv

I am confused by the current state of Emgu GPU functionality (using Emgu 2.4 x64). The methods available from a GPUImage are very limited - I am trying to use it for blob detection. Specifically a code structure like this could use GPU to speed up blob extraction.

Any thoughts on how I could leverage GPU functionality from Emgu? Alternately, what are choices are available to leverage GPUs (other than a rewrite in CUDA)?

```
        using (Image<Gray, Byte> currentGrayFrame = imgCurrentFrame.Convert<Gray, Byte>())
        {
            using (MemStorage storage = new MemStorage())
            {
                currentGrayFrame._SmoothGaussian(3);
                currentGrayFrame._GammaCorrect(1.8d);
                currentGrayFrame._EqualizeHist();
                CvInvoke.cvCanny(currentGrayFrame, currentGrayFrame, 120, 60, 3);
                int blobID = 0;
                for (Contour<System.Drawing.Point> contours = currentGrayFrame.FindContours(CHAIN_APPROX_METHOD.CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, RETR_TYPE.CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, storage);
                     contours != null; contours = contours.HNext)
                {
                    Contour<Point> contour = contours.ApproxPoly(contours.Perimeter * 0.001);
                    if (contour.Area > 100)
                        if (contour.Total > 5)
                        {
                            Rectangle rect = contour.BoundingRectangle;
                            Image<Bgr, Byte> imgBlob = imgCurrentFrame.Copy(rect);
                            {
                                //Bitmap bmpBlob = imgBlob.Bitmap;
                                blobsList.Add(new Blob
                                {
                                    BlobID = ++blobID,
                                    BlobImage = imgBlob,
                                    Location = rect,
                                });
                                //imgBlob.Dispose();
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Whats the question?  How to use CUDA in emgu?

Comment: The question was how to rewrite the above method (canny->contour->bounding boxes) in Emgu using GPUs.

Comment: @Mikos Any progress? I dont see any CudaBlob or CudaInvoke.Blob in emguCV.